# How to check whether my DLL has been loaded by a program

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

The manual way would be to use Procmon,procexp, however I require some form of automation that tells me
"Hey, the DLL that I have tried to hijack has been loaded into the program!"

I've thought of maybe trying to use a DLL to open calculator.exe but I don't think and don't know if that's possible, as such
my question is :
Are there any tell tale signs that can allow me to check that a modified dll has been loaded by maybe adding 1-2 lines of code into the cpp file before compiling into a dll?

Comment: Can't the DLL notify you that it's been loaded? DllMain exists, for example

Comment: how is observing calculator.exe any less manual than running procexp? The question is way too broad imo

Comment: Add logging to your DLL.